# How to Exclude Current Month in Google Analytics Reporting API Call?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Have searched long and hard through much documentation and many stack overflow answers looking for this with no luck. How do I exclude the currrent, incomplete, month in a GA api call?

I've tried &end-date!=CMS, &end-date=PM1, and similar, but nothing seems to work and I can find no relevant documentation. Your help is greatly appreciated. Apologies in advance if there is a better place to ask this question that I'm not aware of.

EDIT 1: example api call

dimensions=ga:year,ga:month&metrics=ga:visitors&filters=ga:country%3D%40United%20States&sort=ga:year,ga:month&start-date=PY2&end-date=PM1&max-results=1000&post-process=month

Comment: Can you provide example code for your api call.

Comment: Let us know what's your query?
Have you use the filters in your query. Do you have tried your query on query explorer? [http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/]

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide the last day of the previous month as `end-date` parameter. The format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. For example:

```
end-date=2013-07-31
```

Comment: I should have specified, this is for a dashboard in Chartio and it needs to exclude the current month without needing to be updated manually each month.